# Unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent

Tags: ios8, hittest, uiwindow

One of my old apps is not working with iOS8. When I start the app up, and try to tap on the screen anywhere, I get this message in my console:

```
unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, 
_windowServerHitTestWindow: <UIWindow: 0x7fe4d3e52660; frame = (0 0; 320 568); 
opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe4d3e2c450>; 
layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fe4d3e86a10>>
```

I'm using an old style MainWindow.xib. In the MainWindow.xib is my Window object, as well as a UINavigationController which has its first View Controller defined within as well. The image below is showing the Outlets connected to the App Delegate.

The white "view" in the screenshot below is the UIWindow. The view on the right is the UINavigationController (nav bar hidden) with the first ViewController defined inside it.

[image]

How do I fix this without recreating the entire app from scratch with a new project?

EDIT: I just discovered there is a TINY strip wherein my buttons will actually receive their taps/clicks.

I've also noticed that my self.view.window is nil. How do I make sure that is set?

[image]

Comment: None of the answers here worked for me. A workaround that solved it was to switch to Storyboards which do not seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Additional to B H answer. Also look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037472/uiwindow-with-wrong-size-when-using-landscape-orientation/26040354#26040354).

Got this issue when launching my landscape only app from portrait orientation (also the app shouldn't be presented in recently opened apps list, which can be seen by pressing Home button twice. Perhaps, iOS somehow caches the orientation and window size).

My code was

```objective-c
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I set `W+H` autoresizing mask for window, it didn't help me, because the window don't being resized on rotation, but the `transform` matrix is changed.

The solution is simple

```objective-c
self.window = [UIWindow new];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

So the frame is set AFTER the window get its orientation from root view controller.

Comment: The self.window.frame = ... did it for me. After that the view is alright on my iPhone5 running iOS8. But - on my iPhone4 running iOS7, all seems to be offset 20 to the left. A rotate of the device get's it back to the right position.

Comment: This did it for an old app with no storyboard. [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

Answer (score 21):

You don't have to add any code to fix this.

Open the main xib file and find "Window" from the left side and enable `Visible at Launch` and `Full Screen at launch`.

[image]

Comment: I'm using storyboard, didn't see anything saying "window".

Answer (score 4):

Check out your Window nib file and make sure it is taking up the full screen.  I had a similar issue on my app where touch events weren't being registered on a strip on the right side.  Once I set my MainWindow.xib to take up the Full Screen, I had no more errors and touch events were working again.  My app was also being displayed in Landscape but my MainWindow.xib had portrait dimensions.

Comment: I've had that problem in the past, so I checked that first. It is set to take up the full screen.

Comment: FWIW, in investigating this I stopped in my home screen VC and repeatedly did `po [self.view superview]`, `po [[self.view superview] superview]`, `po [[[self.view superview] superview] superview]`, etc, until (after 6 layer) I got to UIWindow, which had a size of 320x480, even though everything else was 375x667.  This was a clear cue that UIWindow was not right.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it's just simple setting that's missing some value: Click on **Project**(whatever you named your project) name item then make sure **General** tab is selected and scroll to the bottom. Look for **App icons and Launch Images** make sure there is some value in the **Launch Screen File** field, this should be either Main or `LaunchScreen`

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody finds this useful:

In my case, I had used

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

and that was the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error on an old app that did not have the Default-568h@2x.png launch screen.  When the taller iPhones were first introduced, this was the signal to iOS that the app could handle the new geometry.  Otherwise, it was displayed in a 320x480 window.  Funny, I did not even notice the app was not using the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test `efpies` solution, but the way I fixed it in my app was to replace the MainWindow.xib with a Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am also upgrading my old project to iOS 7 and iOS 8.
Actually, I don't use MainWindow.xib, but creating `window` manually in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

But i have same `unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent` error after launch.

So, in my case, problem was solved by changing deployment target to `6.0` and replacing code in `main.m`:

**Old main.m:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

**New main.m:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([YourAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, and we tried the proposed solutions in this thread without success.

What ended up working for us, was to re-write the logic to be pure programmatically instead of using xib's. After this we don't see the 'unexpected nil window' error and the view is getting the hit all over the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else that stumbles here, I also got this error when I had the `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` size flipped when setting the window's frame.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an old code and after reading the complete code i found this line

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

I handle it according to my logic and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to Enable windows user interaction.

```
window.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score -3):

Using the new ios 8 'nativeBounds' UIScreen property instead of 'bounds' when creating the window fixed the issue for me. No other changes required.

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds]] autorelease];
```

To support previous version too, I do a runtime check with the version:

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]  systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
```