# Custom UIWindow on iOS 8.3 iPad works on simulator but not device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

We have UIWindow code that has worked for years to put up a "blocker" screen.  We noticed recently that on an iOS 8.3 iPad the blocker is offset 256 pixels when the blocker is displayed in the landscape orientation.    There are few oddities:

1) This does not happen on the simulator, only the device

2) If the blocker is shown in portrait it is fine

3) If the blocker is shown in portrait and then rotated to landscape it is fine.

4) The gap is 256 pixels, which is the difference between the width and the height, i.e., 1024 - 768 = 256.

We've recently updated to Xcode 6, so this could be a factor as well...

This problem can be easily replicated by using the default Xcode Master Detail project and making a few minor changes to the "insertNewObject" method as shown here:

```
    UIWindow *blocker;

    - (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {


            blocker = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
            [blocker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.0 green:.0 blue:.0 alpha:.8]];
            [blocker makeKeyAndVisible];

            CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
            [blocker setFrame:r];


    }
```

If you run this code on the simulator, and tap the "+" button you get:

[image]

which is what we expect.

However, this same exact code, running on our 8.3 iPad device gives us:

[image]

Any ideas of why the simulator works and the device doesn't?  Suggestions?  Other things to try?

**[UPDATE]** We've only found one device where is this a problem, an iPad 2.  We've also discovered that setting the rootViewController on the UIWindow "solves" the problem.

Comment: We are experiencing this same issue, also only on iPad 2 hardware. Simulator works fine.
https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios/issues/148

Comment: Would you mind adding your `rootViewController` solution as an "answer" here? Perhaps with code samples and/or screenshots. Thanks! If I find a solution I will answer as well.

Comment: @pkamb - no problem.  I've added a snippet of the code we used to fix the issue.

Comment: same here on iPad 3 with iOS 8.4

Comment: @StefanArn  I got a note on my submitted bug report saying that in iOS 9 they've updated it such that the simulator will show the same issue.  In other words, I think it is up to us to fix the problem.

Comment: @MikeM I was not able to fix it though. I see that the `UIWindow` I create has a wrong orientation based on the behavior of the X and Y coordinate system. But I can't turn `UIWindow` around to landscape, even the `rootViewController` hack does not solve it for me. The only thing I can do now is to substract 256 pixels from the Y coordinate for all iOS Versions starting from 8.3. But that can't be the solution.

Comment: @StefanArn, I think the rootViewController hack is the "right" way to address since it is how view controllers manage rotation.  Also, I had another piece of code that also used a blocker and I had troubles getting it to work as well.  I found that I was doing other rotation which caused the fix not to work.  I'd start by adding a simple view to the root and go from there... good luck :)

Comment: @MikeM you're right: there was an additional transform going on. So now the `rootViewController` hack works for me too. Thank you for the helpful input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix we used:

```
blocker = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
[blocker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.0 green:.0 blue:.0 alpha:.8]];

UIViewController *blockerRoot = [UIViewController new];
blocker.rootViewController = blockerRoot;
CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[blocker setFrame:r];

[blocker makeKeyAndVisible];
```

We also were able to remove rotation adjustment code since now the view controller managed it properly for us (at least for iOS 8 and later).  Here's the code we now use for that: (called when the screen is rotated)

```
    - (void)adjustForRotation
    {

        if ([UIUtil iOS8OrLater]){
        // iOS 8 handles this correctly, no need for adjustments...
            return;
        }

        UIInterfaceOrientation io = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(io)){
            CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGFloat x = r.size.height / 2.0;
            CGFloat y = r.size.width / 2.0;
            self.center = CGPointMake(x, y);       
        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly set the frame of the blocker to the portrait dimensions. It is only being changed when the device is rotated.

Instead, try getting the size from the display to current window when the blocker is being created.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've used a combination of options including [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].  The 256 offset is always the same on the device.  I was actually going to explicitly set it to 300x100 for the sample, but figured the problem would be more obvious with a full screen blocker.