# iOS8: How to show a different view controller when the phone rotates to landscape?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, rotation, uikit

I have a View Controller that is portrait-only. When I rotate the phone I want to display a second View Controller that is landscape-only. How can I get this working on iOS 8?

Under iOS 7, everything works fine: I listen for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, then present the landscape view controller over the first. I use a custom animation controller that replicates the native rotation animation. I animate the `transform` property to rotate the view into place, then call `setStatusBarOrientation:animated:` to update the system.

On iOS8 the visuals work, but after rotation touch handling is broken on the right half of the screen. In fact, any touches received anywhere in the pink area are mapped to `x = 414`. So the touches register, but are assigned an incorrect `x` coordinate.

[image]

This appears to be the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963101/unexpected-nil-window-in-uiapplicationhandleeventfromqueueevent) where the guy describes receiving touches only on a small strip right around the edge of the portrait window frame. This also appears to be related to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037472/uiwindow-with-wrong-size-when-using-landscape-orientation).

The problem seems to be that the underlying UIWindow is not getting rotated by the call to `setStatusBarOrientation:animated:`. Looking at it in the debugger, I see that calling this function changes the **UIDevice** bounds to landscape, but the UIWindow bounds stay in portrait.

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html)

> The two principal functions of a window are to provide an area for displaying its views and to distribute events to the views.

So this touch-distributing function seems to be getting mangled.

Can anyone suggest a way to get this working in iOS 8? Regardless of the new size classes and UITraitCollection stuff, I should still be able to apply a rotation transform to a view and not have that break touch handling. Right?

Alternatively, is there an easier way to present a view controller into landscape without having to implement the animation manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or commenting out the following line from you app delegate code if it exists:

`self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];`

You do not need it now and it affects rotation on iOS8.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, didn't work though. Removing it just made the screen black. Changing it to `self.window = [UIWindow new]` produced the error `unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent`.

Comment: Odd. That sounds like you have no root controller. You should only need   `self.window.rootViewController = <insert root controller>;
    self.window.backgroundColor = <insert color...>;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Comment: I went back to remind myself the effect of the self.window line being in the code on iOS8 and I get the effect you are experiencing. Hardware rotates, but the internal controllers do not receive the rotation and the right hand of the screen stops receiving input. I use `- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to handle rotation changes. I am pretty sure your issue relates to the self.window creation not being required. Can you post your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method?

Comment: Also found I get a black screen with the line removed if the storyboard does not have one of the view controllers marked as the initial view controller. This perhaps is what stimulates the internal self.window to be created properly by xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is iOS 8 bug and I find that it has been fixed in ios 8.3